# A list of anonymous types with inheritance

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Let's say I have the following classes

```
public class Dog{}
public class Bulldog : Dog{}
public class Pitbull : Dog{}
```

I am trying to create a list like this

```
var dogs2 = new[]
{
   new { X = new Bulldog(), Y = 10},
   new { X = new Pitbull(), Y = 20}
}.ToList();
```

But, I am getting the following error `No best type found for implicitly - typed array`
Ok, I guess that makes sense. The system can't figure out that `X is a type of`Dog`

So, I try doing this

```
var dogs1 = Enumerable.Empty<object>()
                      .Select(x => new { X = new Dog (), Y = 0 })
                      .ToList();
dogs1.Add(new { X = new Pitbull(), Y = 10 });
dogs1.Add(new { X = new Bulldog(), Y = 10 });
```

Now, I am getting this error `cannot convert from '<anonymous type: PassingEvents.Bulldog X, int Y>' to '<anonymous type: PassingEvents.Dog X, int>'`. Why can't it convert? Isn't `Bulldog` castable to `Dog`?

Is there a way to fix this, without having to crate a new class? The code below works just fine

```
public class DogCombo
{
    public Dog X;
    public int Y;
}

var dogs3 = new[]
{
    new DogCombo{ X = new Bulldog(), Y = 10},
    new DogCombo{ X = new Pitbull(), Y = 20}
 }.ToList();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why can't it convert? Isn't Bulldog castable to Dog?

Bulldog is convertible to Dog, yes.

Your reasoning is as follows:

- Bulldog is convertible to Dog
- Therefore anonymous-type-with-Bulldog should be convertible to anonymous-type-with-Dog.

This reasoning -- that the properties of the underlying types should imply properties of types under a transformation -- is called *covariance*.

C# supports covariance in certain restricted cases.  They are:

- An array of Bulldog may be used as an array of Dog.  Note that this is *unsafe covariance*, because you can put a Poodle into an array of Dog, but not into an array of Bulldog.  Array covariance is only safe if you never write to the array.
- An `IEnumerable<Bulldog>` may be converted to `IEnumerable<Dog>`. This is safe.  A sequence of bulldogs is a sequence of dogs.  This is also true of a few other generic types, like `IEnumerator<T>`.
- A method which returns a Bulldog may be converted to a delegate for a delegate type that returns a Dog.

C# also supports *contravariance* in some cases. For example, an `IComparable<Dog>` may be converted to `IComparable<Bulldog>`.  A thing which can compare dogs can compare bulldogs. Note that this convertibility is going in the opposite direction, hence *contra* variant.

C# does *not* support any covariance (or contravariance) on *classes*, *structs* or *anonymous types*.

In theory, C# could support contravariance on anonymous types as you desire; it would be safe to do so.  The language and runtime teams have been pitched this feature before. It's simply the case that the language and runtime teams have not prioritized the feature highly enough to actually implement it.

If you think that there is a really good reason to implement covariant conversions on structural types like anonymous types, you can start a discussion on that topic on the Roslyn github forum, and maybe it will be implemented someday.

> Is there a way to fix this, without having to create a new class?

I would suggest that you create a new class. But if you want a cheap and easy workaround: just cast *explicitly* to `Dog`.

Answer (score 8):

You can explicitly cast X to a type of `Dog`:

```
var dogs2 = new[]
{
   new { X = (Dog)new Bulldog(), Y = 10},
   new { X = (Dog)new Pitbull(), Y = 20}
}.ToList();
```